# Why isn't the $Site global variable returning anything?

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is very odd. I'm working on a VF page and none of the `$Site` fields are returning anything -- not even whitespace or an error. I've tried it with about half of the `$Site` fields.

For example, this just renders a blank page (except for the standard header and sidebar):

```
<apex:page>
{!$Site.BaseUrl}
</apex:page>
```

Other global variables, like `$Organization` and `$User`, seem to be working fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global `$Site` variable is available for your Force.com sites (portals/communities). You will need to create a site and add your VisualForce page to the site. There is no site context when you're accessing the VF page from within the org (`/apex/VFPage`).

Comment: Oh. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Can you tell me off the top of your head how I would get the Salesforce instance's base URL from a Page not within a Site?

Comment: I think you can do that with `$CurrentPage` - http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm

Answer (score 1):

That global merge field is applicable only when you are viewing that page within the Site's context. Otherwise, it is 'nop'.